# Shiny App - Having trouble plotting a stock line chart

Tags: r, shiny, quantmod

I am trying to map a stock line chart using quantmod in the shiny app.
Getting an error.
Warning: Error in sourceUTF8: Error sourcing /home/ccc_v1_w_62aa8_36923/asn122362_7/asn122367_1/Dashboard 4Dec/9 Dec Stock APP TESTING/Testing Stock App/server.R
[No stack trace available]
Error in sourceUTF8(serverR, envir = new.env(parent = sharedEnv)) :

```
Server.R
library(quantmod)
shinyServer(function(input, output){
  price <- getSymbols(input$stockInput,
                                  type="line",
                                  from='2019',
                                  theme=chartTheme('white'),
                      auto.assign = F)
                      plot(price, main = input$stockInput)})

ui.R
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Stock Chart"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      #This is a dropdown to select the stock
      selectInput("stockInput", 
                  "Pick your stock:", 
                  c("AMZN","FB","GOOG","NVDA","AAPL"),
                  "AMZN"),selected = "GOOG"),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    ))))
```

Comment: `getSymbol` is crashing, also you dont get price data with this function...

Comment: thanks.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
library(quantmod)
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
  observe({
  price <- getSymbols(req(input$stockInput),
                      type="line",
                      from="2015-01-01",to="2016-01-01",
                      theme=chartTheme('white'),
                      auto.assign = F)
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    plot(price, main = req(input$stockInput))
  })
  })
})

### ui.R
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Stock Chart"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      #This is a dropdown to select the stock
      selectInput("stockInput",
                  "Pick your stock:",
                  choices = c("AMZN","FB","GOOG","NVDA","AAPL"),
                  selected = "GOOG")
      ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
    )))

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for response. Doesn't look like it's working. Coming up with errors:

Warning: Error in getSymbols.yahoo: Unable to import “AAPL”.
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
  48: stop
  47: getSymbols.yahoo
  45: getSymbols

Comment: @Trungle83, Please try again.